# Flutter X Cloud Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Apresenta esse erro. A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 298 pos 10: 'data != null'

Arquivo Pubspec.yaml

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
```

Arquivo Builder.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
```

Arquivo app/ Builder.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "paula.com.healthnow4you"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

Lib/model Exame

```
class Exame {

  String _ID;
  String _CPF;
  String _N_Exame;
  String _Data;
  String _Rotina;
  String _Laudo;


  Exame(this._ID,this._CPF,
      this. _N_Exame,
      this. _Data,
      this. _Rotina,
      this. _Laudo,
      );

  Exame.map(dynamic obj)  {

    this._ID = obj['ID'];
    this._CPF = obj['CPF'];
    this. _N_Exame = obj['Exame'];
    this. _Data = obj['Data'];
    this. _Rotina = obj['Rotina'];
    this. _Laudo = obj['Laudo'];

  }

  String get ID => _ID;
  String get CPF => _CPF;
  String get N_Exame => _N_Exame;
  String get Data => _Data;
  String get Rotina => _Rotina;
  String get Laudo => _Laudo;


  Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){

    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if(_ID != null) {
      map['ID'] = _ID;
    }
    map['CPF'] = _CPF;
    map['Exame'] = _N_Exame;
    map['Data'] = _Data;
    map['Rotina'] = _Rotina;
    map['Laudo'] = _Laudo;
    return map;


  }

  Exame.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, String ID) {

    this._ID = ID ?? '';
    this. _CPF = map['CPF'];
    this. _N_Exame = map['Exame'];
    this. _Data = map['Data'];
    this. _Rotina = map['Rotina'];
    this. _Laudo= map['Laudo'];
  }


}
```

Lib/Pages / Exames

> *import 'dart:async';
> import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> import 'package:healthnow4you/model/exame.dart';
>
> ```
> import 'package:healthnow4you/style/style-app-bar.dart';
>
>
> class ExamePage extends StatefulWidget {
>   @override
>   _ExamePageState createState() => _ExamePageState();
> }
>
> class _ExamePageState extends State<ExamePage> {
>   List<Exame> items;
>   var db = Firestore.instance;
>
>   StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> exameInscricao;
>
>   @override
>   void initState() {
>     super.initState();
>
>     items = List();
>     exameInscricao?.cancel();
>
>     exameInscricao = db.collection("Exame").snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
>       final List<Exame> exame = snapshot.documents
>           .map(
>             (documentSnapshot) => Exame.fromMap(
>                 documentSnapshot.data, documentSnapshot.documentID),
>           )
>           .toList();
>
>       setState(() {
>         this.items = exame;
>       });
>     });
>   }
>
>   @override
>   void dispose() {
>     exameInscricao?.cancel();
>     super.dispose();
>   }
>
> //class _ExameState extends State<ExamePage> {
>   bool _isChecked = false;
>   bool _value1 = false;
>   bool _value2 = false;
>
>   //we omitted the brackets '{}' and are using fat arrow '=>' instead, this is dart syntax
>   void _value1Changed(bool value) => setState(() => _value1 = value);
>
>   void _value2Changed(bool value) => setState(() => _value2 = value);
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Scaffold(
>       appBar: AppBar(
>         backgroundColor: Colors.white,
>         automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
>         leading: IconButton(
>           icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
>           color: Colors.black38,
>           onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
>         ),
>         title: Logo(),
>       ),
>       body: Column(
>         children: <Widget>[
>           Expanded(
>           child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> (
>           stream: getListaExame ( ),
>     builder: (context, snapshot) {
>       switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
>         case ConnectionState.none:
>         case ConnectionState.waiting:
>           return Center (
>             child: CircularProgressIndicator ( ),
>
>           );
>
>         default:
>           List<DocumentSnapshot> documentos =
>               snapshot.data.documents;
>
>           return ListView.builder (
>             itemCount: documentos.length,
>             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
>               return ListTile (
>                 title: Text ( items[index].N_Exame,
>                     style: TextStyle ( fontSize: 22 ) ),
>                 subtitle: Text ( items[index].Data,
>                     style: TextStyle ( fontSize: 22 ) ),
>                 leading: Column (
>                   children: <Widget>[
>                     IconButton (
>                         icon: const Icon( Icons.delete ),
>                         onPressed: () {
>                           _deleteExame ( context, documentos[index], index );
>                         }
>
>                     )
>
>                   ],
>
>                 ),
>               );
>             },
>           );
>       }
>     }
>     ),
>           ),
>         ],
>       ),
>
>
>     );
>   }
>
>   Stream<QuerySnapshot> getListaExame() {
>     return Firestore.instance.collection('Exame').snapshots();
>   }
>
>   void _deleteExame(
>       BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot doc, int position) async {
>     var db = Firestore.instance;
>
>     db.collection('Exame').document(doc.documentID).delete();
>
>     setState(() {
>       items.removeAt(position);
>     });
>   }
> }*
> ```